# C - Save SHELL output in a file after System function call

Tags: c, file, shell, system, ping

I need help to save my shell output after a System call from a C console application.

I need to save in a file, for doing some op., the output of a shell command ping.
I have already try to use this command:

```
system(ping -c 5 google.com ./out > output.txt);
```

but I'll find an empty file only and the command not work.

Does anyone can help me? (I'm working in UNIX/LINUX)

Comment: What's that `./out` there? It should be: `system("ping -c 5 google.com > output.txt");`

Comment: Thank you very much! You have solved my problem!

Comment: @l3x, please post as an answer so OP can accept and close this question

Comment: @user3629249 Done! I wasn't entirely sure what OP was trying to achieve. Hence, I didn't post an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The last argument to `ping` command is the destination that you want to ping. Because you have a stray argument `./out`, `ping` attempts to ping that and obviously the command fails.
Checking the return code of `system` command would tell you whether it succeeded or not. So remove it and passing correct argument to `ping` will fix it:

```
system("ping -c 5 google.com > output.txt");
```

Considering you want to redirect the output to a text file and want to do some processing on it, it may be more appropriate to use [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function and read the output directly.

For example,

```
FILE *fp;
char buf[1024];

fp = popen("ping -c 5 google.com", "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
}

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
   /*process each line here*/
}
```